# How declare a constants file with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

how would one create a constants class or helper in Ember?

something like create a constants.js and add

```
export const testme = 3;
export const testtoo = 4;
```

then in a controller I'd

```
import constants from 'constants';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are exporting correctly but importing incorrectly 
your import should look like this

```
import { testme, testtoo } from './constants';
```

but I would take different approach and create hash constant instead (in constants.js file)

```
export default { TEST1: '1', TEST2: '2' };
```

then import like

```
import CONSTANTS from 'constants'

CONSTANTS.TEST1 === '1'
```

Comment: where would that `export default { TEST1: '1', TEST2: '2' };` statement go?

Comment: wrote that in my answer now

Comment: where would the `constants.js` file need to go so that it would be loaded and available for import?

Comment: @jeffdill2 wherever in your app directory, and you import it depending file path `import { testme, testtoo } from './constants';` if file you are importing to is in same directory

Comment: worked great except I had to import using `import CONSTANTS from '../constants-test` rather than `import CONSTANTS from './constants-test'` still not pro'ed out on the whole import thing... thanks so much